# How to make my server fetch js file instead of fetching html again?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, server

I have an index.html which uses bundle.js file. It works fine in the local machine. But when try to do the same thing with server, it just shows only html file content. when looked at the code in console instead of regular js code the bundle.js file contains same html code. This the server code I have used.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
const PORT=3012; 

fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, html) {

    http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
        response.write(html);  
        response.end();  
    }).listen(PORT);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to serve your bundle.js file and another files without using express or another already made tested and preferred way, you can  serve any file you like (see "routeToFile" function).

```
//Return the file path you want to serve to that request url
const routeToFile = ({url}) => {
    if(url === '/'){
        return './index.html';
    }

    return `.${url}`;
}
```

With "mimeTypes" array you can guess the right mime type by just checking the file extension (mimeTypes[fileExtension]).

```
//File mime types for content type response
const mimeTypes = {
    '.html': 'text/html',
    '.js': 'text/javascript',
    '.css': 'text/css',
    '.json': 'application/json',
    '.png': 'image/png',
    '.jpg': 'image/jpg'
};
```

If there is an error, for instance if the file don't exist, just send the error code, or a page you like too (see "onError" function)

```
//If the file is missing or there is an error
const onError = (error, response) => {
    if(error.code == 'ENOENT') {
        response.writeHead(404);
    }
    else {
        response.writeHead(500);
        console.error(error);
    }

    response.end();
}
```

Finally, the main function to run all of this, will be:

```
//Create the http server
http.createServer((req, res) => {

    const filePath = routeToFile(req)
    const fileExtension = String(path.extname(filePath)).toLowerCase();
    const contentType = mimeTypes[fileExtension] || 'application/octet-stream';

    fs.readFile(filePath, function(error, content) {
        if (error) {
            return onError(error, res)
        }
        else {
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
            res.end(content, 'utf-8');
        }
    });

}).listen(PORT, () =>{
    console.log(`server start at port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Don't forget the requires, or it won't run :D

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const PORT = 3012
```

Comment: If you have any issue I would like to help you with, but you have to be more detailed and describe the issue.